# MVC / jQuery - Action not being hit when called via $.ajax()?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to do the simplest of things in MVC using jQuery: submit a form.

Here's my code that calls to the action:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Save", "Material")";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data
});
```

When this gets executed, nothing happens. Nothing at all. The action isn't hit, the page doesn't redirect, nothing.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools (network & console)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var data={};
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetMapMarkers")", data, function(result) {
});
```

Your controller should look like:

```
public JsonResult GetMapMarkers()
{
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var url = "@Url.Action('Save', 'Material')";
```

Try changing your inner (or outer for that matter) double quotes to single quotes.

Comment: OP pasted code containing a variable initialization that used double quotes throughout.  It doesn't compile like that and would explain why it doesn't execute.  While it may not be the entire solution to his problem, it is still a problem.

Comment: Negative.  The @Url.Action("Save","Material") is a server side code block and will get processed and replaced with an appropriate URL regardless of what surrounds it.  For example, the HTML that gets rendered may be `var url="/Material/Save";` after the razor view engine processes it, which is valid javascript.

Comment: Additionally, since this is either a C# or VB.NET code block, the single quotes would signify a single character, and neither `Save` nor `Material` is a single character.  It would fail to compile (at runtime).